# Multi layer variable substitution in shell.. possible?

Tags: shell

I have multiple variables in a shell script; i was trying to save some code duplication and wanted to do something like following

```
# variables
FLAG=SIM
SIM_ICR_KEY_VAL="http://www.example.com/simi/icr"
REAL_ICR_KEY_VAL="http://www.example.com/real"
```

Based on the FLAG value i want to access the correct variable (without using IF's)
When i try this it echos the variable name & not the value itself.

```
 echo $(echo ${FLAG}_ICR_KEY_VAL)
```

On further note; i need to use these substitutions inline in a sed statememt:

```
sed "s!${ISTR_KEY}=.*!${ISTR_KEY}=${SIM_ISTR_KEY_VAL}!" > tmp.file
```

... i am not sure its possible or not, please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection can be achieved with the infamous `eval`:

```
eval thisvar=\$${FLAG}_INC_KEY_VAL;
echo "We are using $thisvar"
```

Whenever you find yourself dynamically synthesizing a variable name, though, you are probably Doing It Wrong. You should consider alternatives like arrays:

```
ICR_KEY_VAL[0]="http://www.example.com/simi/icr"
ICR_KEY_VAL[1]="http://www.example.com/real"

SIM=0

echo ${ICR_KEY_VAL[$SIM]}
```

Comment: @sid: Glad to hear -- never give up believing in the power of the shell! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it directly, but in bash you can do it indirectly:

```
FLAG=SIM
SIM_ICR_KEY_VAL="http://www.example.com/simi/icr"
REAL_ICR_KEY_VAL="http://www.example.com/real"
FLAG_ICR_KEY_VAL=${FLAG}_ICR_KEY_VAL
sed "s!${ISTR_KEY}=.*!${ISTR_KEY}=${!FLAG_ISTR_KEY_VAL}!" > tmp.file
```